# Pandas dataframe combine multiple logical operators in an OR statement

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a date column.

```
ACCTOPNDTE ACTNUM
2012-10-01  1234
2013-07-03  6666
2012-12-09  3333
```

I want to pass in an input year and get back all rows in the current fiscal year (Nov - Oct) and last fiscal year.
So if I pass 2012--> I want 1234
If I pass 2013, I want: 6666 and 3333
So condition1:

```
df[df[ACCTOPNDTE ].year = $inputYear AND df[ACCTOPNDTE ].month<=10]
```

condition 2:

```
df[df[ACCTOPNDTE ].year = $inputYear -1 ]
```

condition 3:

```
df[df[ACCTOPNDTE ].year = $inputYear -2  AND df[ACCTOPNDTE ].month > 10]
```

How do I combine these 3 conditions in an OR statement, I cannot seem to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) with [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), for `bitwise AND` use `&` and for `bitwise OR` `|`:

```
m1 = (df['ACCTOPNDTE'].dt.year == inputYear) & (df['ACCTOPNDTE'].dt.month <= 10)
m2 = (df['ACCTOPNDTE'].dt.year == inputYear - 1)
m3 = (df['ACCTOPNDTE'].dt.year == inputYear - 2) & (df['ACCTOPNDTE'].dt.month > 10)

df = df[m1 | m2 | m3]
```

Comment: Thanks. In pandas, when do I use bitwise & and when do I use the keyword 'and'?

Comment: @Victor in pandas obviously working with 1d arrays (Series) or 2d arrays (Dataframes), so use bitwise &. Veru rate is used and for working with scalars.